# Finding expected value when conditional distribution is known

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

If the distribution of $Y$ *conditional* on $X=x$ is known, and the distribution of  $X$ is known, what would be the general process for finding the expected value $\Bbb E[Y]$? *IS* there a general process, or does one need to know the exact distributions?

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$Search up "law of total expectation". For example, if $X$ has density $f_X$, then $\E[Y]=\int \E[Y\mid X=x]f_X(x)\, dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that:

$$E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]]$$

Comment: and $E(Y|X)=E(Y|X=\cdot)\circ X$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the notation you have used.